# Assign/Export a MIDI channel to one speaker only

Tags: midi

Hello fellow musicians,

I have a question that I feel should be pretty simple but I haven't been able to find a solution.
I am preparing an opera and I have written my bass parts and the piano as **two separate channels** in a midi file (with Aria Maestosa).

Now I would like to put the **piano channel in my right ear** and **the bass channel in my left ear**.

I know this is possible because I've seen it here http://www.cyberbass.com/Opera/Bizet/bizet_carmen.htm

My target is MP3 files, so I don't mind if MIDI doesn't support mono channels and if this can only be done at export to mp3 time.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2) defines controller 10 as pan.
Set it to the minimum in one channel and to the maximum in the other channel.

Comment: That doesn't entirely cut off the sound in the other ear but it should be good enough thank you I didn't know this "pan" term.